# How to log checkpoint location every time one is saved with pytorch lightning?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am currently saving a checkpoint every validation epoch like so

```
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
        # dirpath=checkpoints_path,
        filename="fa_classifier_{epoch:02d}",
        every_n_epochs=val_every_n_epochs,
        save_top_k=-1,
        # monitor=
    )
```

and

```
      trainer = Trainer(
            callbacks=[checkpoint_callback],
            # overfit_batches=1,
            # fast_dev_run=True,
            default_root_dir=checkpoints_path,
            check_val_every_n_epoch=val_every_n_epochs,
            max_epochs=max_epochs,
            gpus=1
        )
```

I would like to interfere with the process, and simply add a log line after a checkpoint has been saved, with the location in which it was saved.

I don't know how to access that data, and at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

You can log the checkpoint path you want in `on_validation_end` of your `LightningModule`. `self.trainer.default_root_dir` would get what you want.

Or simply overwrite `on_validation_end` in `ModelCheckpoint`. Inherit everything `ModelCheckpoint` has done for you and log what you want.

These are the highly customized methods but I think what you really want can be done by simply set `verbose` parameter `True` in `ModelCheckpoint` callback.

Comment: thanks. Can you show code please?

Comment: or you can simply set the `verbose` parameters `True` in your `ModelCheckpoint` callback.

Comment: Can you show code please?

Comment: Also, what if I want to interfere and change the location based on some runtime variable?